# how to echo and saparate multiple users information in the same table to each of their page

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I want to be able to create multiple users, and echo their information to welcome.php, but when i create first user the first user info's appears in the welcome.php and when i create the second user the second user info's carry's the first users info ignoring the second user that i created info's, i don't know if anyone could understand me, so i am wondering how do i separate each users info's and allow it to echo when the first user enters its username and password and it echos the first users info's and when the second users enters its username and password it echos the second users info's only without joining it into the first users info's just to separate them in a way that when the first user enters its username and password its echos the first users info's, and when the second user enters its username and password its echos the second users info's, i hope you guys could i understand what i mean apologies for my english, just hope is possible.

here is what i have tried so far:

```
<?php

//  Connect to the database

$db = mysql_connect("$Sname","$Uname","$Pname") or die("Could not connect to the Database."); 
$select = mysql_select_db("$Dname") or die("Could not select the Database."); 

$tnumber2 = "{$_SESSION['tnumber2']}"; 


$sql="SELECT * FROM `$Tname` LIMIT 0, 25 ;"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>
```

and am also echo infos from another table in the same welcome which is:

```
<?php

//  Connect to the database

$db = mysql_connect("$Sname","$Uname","$Pname") or die("Could not connect to the Database."); 
$select = mysql_select_db("$Dname") or die("Could not select the Database."); 

$tnumber2 = "{$_SESSION['tnumber2']}"; 


$sql="SELECT * FROM `$UPname` LIMIT 0, 25 ;"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

on this one i am echoing this with html tables

```
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Start looping table row 
?>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="height:27px; color:#333" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong><?php echo $rows['pdate']; ?></strong></td>
                        <td class="style007" style="height: 27px; width: 111px;" color:"#333" bgcolor="#E6E6E6" ><strong><?php echo $rows['act']; ?></strong></td>
                        <td class="style007" style="height: 27px" color:"#333" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong><?php echo $rows['paddress']; ?></strong></td>
                        <td class="style007" style="height: 27px; width: 60px;" color:"#333" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong><?php echo $rows['up']; ?></strong></td>
                        </tr>
<?php
// Exit looping and close connection 
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

any help on how to make this perfect will be appreciated

Comment: show table structure and make sure you have more than one data in the table

Comment: $sql="CREATE TABLE `$Tname` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`tnumber2` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`results` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
`idate` TEXT NOT NULL, 
`iaddress` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
`tstatus` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
`saddress` TEXT NOT NULL, 
`scountry` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
`ddate` TEXT NOT NULL,
`daddress` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`pdate` TEXT NOT NULL, 
`act` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
`paddress` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
`up` TEXT NOT NULL, 
UNIQUE (`tnumber2`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM";

Comment: $sql="CREATE TABLE `$UPname` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`tnumber2` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`pdate` TEXT NOT NULL, 
`act` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
`paddress` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
`up` TEXT NOT NULL, 
UNIQUE (`tnumber2`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM";

Answer (score 1):

Let's try rewriting this code and using MySQLi instead?

```
<?php

    // Making the connection.
    $connection = new mysqli('localhost', "root", "ascent", "tcms");

    // Making sure that the connection is successful.
    if ($connection->connect_error)
    {
        trigger_error("Database connection error: " . $connection->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    // Getting the result from the table.
    $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM phptracker_peers LIMIT 0, 25;");

    // Checking if there is a result or the query is wrong.
    $result === FALSE ? trigger_error("Database query error: " . $result->error, E_USER_ERROR) : NULL;

    // Echo the details of the users.
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) // Fetching it with the column names, instead of number
    {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:27px; color:#333" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong><?php echo $row['pdate']; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="style007" style="height: 27px; width: 111px;" color:"#333" bgcolor="#E6E6E6" ><strong><?php echo $row['act']; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="style007" style="height: 27px" color:"#333" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong><?php echo $row['paddress']; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="style007" style="height: 27px; width: 60px;" color:"#333" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong><?php echo $row['up']; ?></strong></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

The other query goes the same way as this one with MySQLi, with just one difference:
You don't have to connect again, just use this `$connection` .

Why using MySQLi? MySQL is deprecate in PHP 5.5 and will be removed in the next version. It's missing a lot of functionality and security that PDO / MySQLi has.

Comment: Had some mistakes, now they're fixed.

Comment: This is really odd. I have no idea what might be causing this, maybe enable full error output of mysql and PHP? Also make sure you have more than 1 user in the table.

Comment: yes of course, i have more than one user in the table

Answer (score 0):

First correct this two lines

```
$db = mysql_connect("$Sname","$Uname","$Pname") or die("Could not connect to the Database."); 
$select = mysql_select_db("$Dname",$db) or die("Could not select the Database.");
```

You have to pass connection varible for select database